# VB and general logical undarstanding

Tags: arrays, vb.net

My problem is I can't undarstand the logic of  Do While Not blFound And intCounter < intPoitns.Length bacause in order do while loop start executing is both statements have to be true so if Not blFound it is mean it is true but it is assign to Boolean value false, so why loop executes and does Not apply only to blFound or also for intCounter. It looks so easy but my brain does not process it in the same time if some one could explain it pleas in very simple language would very appriciate. Thank you for your time!

Here is example:
Assume that intValidNumbers is an array of integers. Write code that searches the array for the value 247. If the value is founf, display message it is position in the array. If not found display a message indicating so.

```
    Dim intPoitns() As Integer = {11, 42, 322, 24, 247}
    Dim strInput As String = InputBox("Enter integer", "Data needed")
    Dim intInput As Integer
    Dim blFound As Boolean = False
    Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim intPosition As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(strInput, intInput) Then
        Do While Not blFound And intCounter < intPoitns.Length
            If intPoitns(intCounter) = intInput Then
                blFound = True
                intPosition = intCounter
            End If
            intCounter += 1
        Loop
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("have to enter integer number")
    End If

    If blFound Then
        lblResult.Text = ("You found" & intPosition + 1)
    Else
        lblResult.Text = ("not Found")
    End If
```

Comment: As a side note, writing this line like this would be clearer (for human readability - the compiler doesn't care):
Do While (Not blFound)  And (intCounter < intPoitns.Length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Not` applies only to `blFound`.  So think of it like this:

```
Do While (Not blFound) And (intCounter < intPoitns.Length)
    If intPoitns(intCounter) = intInput Then
        blFound = True
        intPosition = intCounter
    End IF
    intCounter += 1
Loop
```

So given that `blFound = False` we can see that `(Not blFound)` == `(Not False)` == `(True)`

Additionally, if `blFound = True` then we get `(Not blFound)` == `(Not True)` == `(False)`

Answer (score 0):

You're right, for `do while` to work, the condition has to be true.

You have 2 conditions connected by `And` so both of them must be true.

Initially both are:

1. `Not blFound` is true as `blFound` is set to `False`.
2. `intCounter < intPoitns.Length` is true as `intCounter` is 0 and `intPoitns.Length` is 5.

Then you loop through the array `intPoitns`. The loop will be stopped if either of the conditions in `do while` becomes false:

1. `Not blFound` can become false if `blFound` becomes true - which means you found your item.
2. `intCounter < intPoitns.Length` becomes false if the `intCounter` becomes 5 which means you got to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Do while loop executes because both your conditions blFound , intCounter < intPoitns.Length are true

blFound is set to false initially, so **Not blFound** is true

intCounter which is 0 is less than intPoitns.Length which is 5

so true and true will execute the loop